# Hibernate/SQL Server Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

Converting a MySQL database to a SQL Server 2008 database using Java + Hibernate. Running into this strange error message.

I know it's supposed to mean that an integer somewhere is too big to fit into the numeric(x,y) that it corresponds to on the SQL Server database, but I can't see anywhere where that is the case.

It happens whenever I try to add things to a Player's statistics. Here's Player.java attributes

```
@Entity(name = "player")
public class Player {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Integer playerId;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "playerposition", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "playerid"))
@Column(name = "position")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
Set<String> positions = new HashSet<String>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="player")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
Set<PlayerSeason> seasons = new HashSet<PlayerSeason>();


@Column
String name;
@Column
String nickName;
@Column
Date birthDay;
@Column
Date deathDay;
@Column
String battingHand;
@Column
String throwingHand;
@Column
String birthCity;
@Column
String birthState;
@Column
String college;
@Column
Date firstGame;
@Column
Date lastGame;
```

Here is PlayerSeason.java attributes

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name = "playerseason")
public class PlayerSeason implements Serializable {

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "playerid", referencedColumnName = "playerid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Player player;

@Id
@Column
public Integer year;

@Column
int gamesPlayed;
@Column
double salary;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="id")
BattingStats battingStats;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="id")
FieldingStats fieldingStats;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="id")
PitchingStats pitchingStats;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="id")
CatchingStats catchingStats;
```

Here's the CatchingStats.java attributes

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="catchingstats")
public class CatchingStats implements Serializable{

@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="playerid"),
    @JoinColumn(name="year")
})
PlayerSeason id;

@Column
Integer passedBalls;
@Column
Integer wildPitches;
@Column
Integer stealsAllowed;
@Column
Integer stealsCaught;
```

I am 95% sure that the issue is with statistics because when I don't add any thing to a Player's PlayerSeasons's "season" set, it works. But as soon as I try to add ANY statistics (catching, hitting or otherwise) it throws the exception and Hibernate does not persist the Player.

Can someone spot the issue?

-----EDIT--------
Here's the ddl for the database

```
create table player (
playerId        numeric(10,0)   IDENTITY(10000,5) primary key,
name            varchar(100)        not null,
nickName        varchar(255),
birthDay        date,
deathDay        date,
battingHand     varchar(1)      check (battingHand in ('L', 'R', 'S')),
throwingHand    varchar(1)      check (throwingHand in ('L', 'R')),
birthCity       varchar(50),
birthState      varchar(2),
college         varchar(50),
firstGame       date,
lastGame        date,
CONSTRAINT uniqueConstraint_Player UNIQUE (name, birthDay, deathDay));

create table playerposition (
playerId        numeric(10,0),
position        varchar(10),
primary key(playerId, position),
foreign key(playerId) references player on delete cascade);

create table playerseason (
playerId        numeric(10,0)   references player on delete cascade,
year            numeric(4,0),
gamesPlayed     numeric(3,0),
salary          numeric(12,2),
primary key (playerId, year));

create table battingstats (
playerId        numeric(10,0),
year            numeric(4,0),
atBats          numeric(4,0),
hits            numeric(4,0),
doubles         numeric(4,0),
triples         numeric(4,0),
homeRuns        numeric(4,0),
runsBattedIn    numeric(4,0),
strikeouts      numeric(4,0),
walks           numeric(4,0),
hitByPitch      numeric(4,0),
intentionalWalks        numeric(4,0),
steals          numeric(4,0),
stealsAttempted numeric(4,0),
primary key(playerId, year),
foreign key(playerId, year) references playerseason on delete cascade);

create table catchingstats (
playerId        numeric(10,0),
year            numeric(4,0),
passedBalls     numeric(4,0),
wildPitches     numeric(4,0),
stealsAllowed   numeric(4,0),
stealsCaught    numeric(4,0),
primary key(playerId, year),
foreign key(playerId, year) references playerseason on delete cascade);

create table fieldingstats (
playerId        numeric(10,0),
year            numeric(4,0),
errors          numeric(4,0),
putOuts         numeric(4,0),
primary key(playerId, year),
foreign key(playerId, year) references playerseason on delete cascade);

create table pitchingstats (
playerId        numeric(10,0),
year            numeric(4,0),
outsPitched     numeric(4,0),
earnedRunsAllowed   numeric(4,0),
homeRunsAllowed     numeric(4,0),
strikeouts      numeric(4,0),
walks           numeric(4,0),
wins            numeric(4,0),
losses          numeric(4,0),
wildPitches     numeric(4,0),
battersFaced    numeric(4,0),
hitBatters      numeric(4,0),
saves           numeric(4,0),
primary key(playerId, year),
foreign key(playerId, year) references playerseason on delete cascade); 

create table team (
teamId          varchar(3),
otherId         varchar(3),
name            varchar(50),
league          varchar(2),
yearFounded     numeric(4,0),
yearLast        numeric(4,0),
primary key(teamId));   

create table teamseason (
teamId          varchar(3),
year            numeric(4,0),
gamesPlayed     int,
wins            int  check (wins >= 0),
losses          int check (losses >= 0),
rank            int,
totalAttendance int,
primary key(teamId, year),
foreign key(teamId) references team);

create table teamseasonplayer (
teamId          varchar(3),
year            numeric(4,0),
playerId        numeric(10,0),
primary key(teamId,year,playerId),
foreign key (teamId) references team,
foreign key (playerId) references player);
```

-----EDIT--------
 Here's the stack trace as printed by Eclipse

`Apr 30, 2014 2:19:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 8115, SQLState: S0008
Apr 30, 2014 2:19:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
Apr 30, 2014 2:19:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at dataaccesslayer.HibernateUtil.persistPlayer(HibernateUtil.java:131)
    at conversion.Convert.convertPlayers(Convert.java:116)
    at conversion.Convert.main(Convert.java:30)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 15 more`

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: You can try to use https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/ so you can see the statement with the parameters while the error occurs.

Comment: It might be that Hibernate is validating the data types, as opposed to the actual values. Many of the columns you have defined for statistics are numeric(4,0), so Hibernate might be complaining that this data type isn't large enough to store an Integer. Have you tried increasing the size of these data types?